# How to check Magento Connect 2.0 extension source before downloading

Tags: magento

I'm leery of just installing community extensions, even with my version control. Is there a way to get the tgz so I can unpack it and inspect the extension before installing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described on [this site](http://turnkeye.com/blog/download-module-archive-magento-connect/), Magento Connect 2.0 has a specific format that is easy to decipher. 1st get the Magento Connect 2.0 key. Example:
`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Raveinfosys_Deleteorder`

Then go to [Magento Commerce website for that extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-deleteorders.html) to find its version in the **Release Notes** tab. For this example, the latest version is 1.0.3

Now, combine the original key into this URL:
`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Raveinfosys_Deleteorder/1.0.3/Raveinfosys_Deleteorder-1.0.3.tgz`

I specifically use this command to download the extension to my work's internal server:
<kbd>wget http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Raveinfosys_Deleteorder/1.0.3/Raveinfosys_Deleteorder-1.0.3.tgz</kbd>
... and then I'll normally make changes to those files to fit our template, ie change from `default/default` to `default/my_template`. Once I'm all happy I re-`tar` these files, `scp` the new tar-ball to my live site, and `tar -xzvf` via the ssh shell at Magento root.

I don't use magento connect... probably should, just can't bring myself to "trust" it blindly.

Or to make generic:
`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Package_Name/[ver]/Package_Name-[ver].tgz`

Comment: This is probably a little simpler. http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Comment: Yes, is simpler, but my OCD needs to know why and have less voodoo.

Answer (score 2):

Some websites offer the links or proxied links to download any mangeto package from mangento connect as `.tgz` file (that is a gzip'ed tar-file). You get the [standard magento PEAR package](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension) then.

These sites require the *Magento Connect key* to obtain the package:

1. [Direct Download Magento Extension Without Pear (Tangkoko)](http://www.tangkoko.com/direct-download-magento-extension/)
2. [Download Magento Extension (http://freegento.com/)](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) (only latest package version)

The first site offers a link to the package on the Magento Connect web-server, so that you can see how it works.

For Magento Connect 2.0 it is also written about how it works in [a blog-post](http://turnkeye.com/blog/download-module-archive-magento-connect/) and there is a bash script that shows it pretty well [on github](https://github.com/elcash/mageunit-satellite/blob/master/download_extension_tarball).